# How do I connect my login screen to an Access database using classes

Tags: java, netbeans

I am currently working on a project that i need to do for my IT practical assessment task for high school. I have created a login screen using Netbeans and have to connect to a database while separating the code into different classes etc. I have created the gui and have created a utilities class where I plan to upload all the information from the gui into the database. My problem now is that i have no clue how to do it. Any help or advice on how to do this would be appreciated

I have tried doing research and watching youtube stuff for it but i have come up with nothing unfortunately

Comment: Look into using the [UCanAccess JDBC Driver](https://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html).

Answer (score 0):

If in need of tutorials for database connection i'd suggest you watch youtube tutorials from Tutus funny. The link to the channel is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4vpJJH2PZU&t=1731s&pp=ygUZdHV0dXMgZnVubnkgamF2YSBwcm9qZWN0cw%3D%3D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).